# How to derive this probability generating function?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, generating-functions

The question is as follows:

"A fair coin is tossed repeatedly until two heads occur consecutively. The random variable $X$ represents the number of tosses up to and including the two consecutive heads. Show that the probability generating function for $X$ is given by
$$\mathrm{G}(z)=\frac{z^2}{4-2z-z^2}"$$

I've made the attempts to find $\mathrm{P}(X=r)$ for $r=2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ in hopes to recognise a pattern in order to sum the series, and I happened to get
$$\mathrm{P}(X=2)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2, \mathrm{P}(X=3)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3, \mathrm{P}(X=4)=2\times\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4, \mathrm{P}(X=5)=3\times\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5 \quad \mathrm{and} \quad\mathrm{P}(X=6)=5\times\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^6$$
but I'm struggling to spot any pattern to sum
$$\sum_{r=2}^{\infty}z^r\mathrm{P}(X=r)$$
in order to reach the given expression.

Comment: Hint:  say  you are counting the strings that end with their first $HH$.  Then prior to that $HH$, every prior step is either $T$ or $HT$.  Thus the generating function for that count is $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (x+x^2)^ix^2$.  Now evaluate this series and adapt it to the probability variant.

Comment: Side note:  since the string prior to the concluding $HH$ consists of series of steps of either length $1$ or length $2$, counting them is effectively the same as counting the Fibonacci numbers...which is why the generating function looks so much like the generating function for the Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $P_n$ be the probability that the string ends on the $n^{th}$ toss.  Then $P_1=0,P_2=\frac 14$.

We work recursively from there.

Good strings of length longer than $2$ must begin with either $T$ or $HT$, with probabilities $\frac 12$ and $\frac 14$ respectively. Thus, for $n>2$ $$P_n=\frac 12P_{n-1}+\frac 14P_{n-2}$$.

Now let $F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_nx^n$ denote the generating function.  We have $$F(x)=\frac {x^2}4+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}P_nx^n=\frac {x^2}4+\frac 12\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}P_{n-1}x^n+\frac 14\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}P_{n-2}x^n$$

Thus $$F(n)=\frac {x^2}4+\left(\frac x2+\frac {x^2}4\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P_nx^n=\frac {x^2}4+\left(\frac x2+\frac {x^2}4\right)F(n)$$

And the rest is straight forward.

Note:  as discussed in the comments, the connection to the Fibonacci numbers is strong.  Indeed, the number of good strings of a fixed length is given by those numbers (since the string prior to the final $HH$ consists of steps $T$ and $HT$, one of which has length $1$ and the other has length $2$).